# Just curious. How to select an element in jquery using its class and then change its id attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML:

```
 <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2">
                        <div class="col-md-2">   <label class="control-label">Select Your Region</label> </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5">      
                        <label class="radio-inline radio1"> <input  class="radio_usa" type="radio" name="optradio" > USA  </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline radio2">  <input  class="radio_outside" type="radio" name="optradio"> Outside USA    </label>
                                </div>
                    </div>

                    <br><br>


 <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2">
 <label class=" control-label">Phone Number of Friend</label> 
  <input type="number" name="phone" class="form-control textbox input-lg phone" id="focusedInput" placeholder="Enter phone number" /> 

 </div>

<div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2">
 <label class=" control-label">Email Id of Friend</label>
   <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control textbox input-lg email" id="focusedInput" placeholder="Enter Email Id"/>
                    </div>  


</div>
```

jquery:

??

How to write jquery to select an element using class like selecting above input element using ".phone" and then changing its id i.e. "#focusedInput" to "#disabledInput".

Comment: The real question is, why would you ever change an ID, sounds like an X/Y problem

Comment: In case you don't know what the XY Problem is, here is a good [explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: To use bootstraps feature. ID of focusedInput gives some feature and id of disabledInput gives another. I wanted to change the feature on a button click.(disable the input box)

Comment: Updated the question to give insight of my problem. @adeneo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` attribute is not what gives your input boxes the bootstrap styles. To disable the input box, you should just add the `disabled` attribute to the input element.

In jQuery 1.6+, use the `.prop()` function:

```
$('.phone').prop('disabled', true);
```

And if you are using jQuery 1.5 or lower, use the `.attr()` function:

```
$('.phone').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Just the thing i wanted to know about bootstrap not using id. I am confused now though about how bootstrap gets to know about which element to modify if not by id or class. I removed all special things and keywords related to bootstrap from my input tag and still the property of focus was there on my text box. I think i will read the bootstrap docs to get the idea.

Comment: Bootstrap automatically applies some styles to all `input` tags as soon as you add the stylesheet to your web page. Other styles are only applied when you give elements a certain class, such as `class="form-control"`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this to change attribute id.

```
  $(".phone").attr("id", "yourNewId");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `.phone` selector only matches a single element, you can do this using `prop`:

```
$('.phone').prop('id', 'disabledInput');
```

However, I would suggest that changing the `id` at runtime is not good practice to follow.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.phone').attr('id', 'disabledInput');
```

Use `attr()` to change the id